# SQLite3 db Android inserting nulls

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
String TABLE_NAME = "WORD";
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
          "(WORD TEXT, DEFINITION TEXT, DAY TEXT)");
         //find out if we have entered data already
             ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
             cv.put("WORD", "nuttin");
             cv.put("DEFINITION", "nuttin");
             cv.put("DAY", "nuttin");
             db.insert("WORD", null, cv );

             ContentValues cvUpdates = new ContentValues();
             cvUpdates.put("WORD", "   ");
             cvUpdates.put("DEFINITION", "   ");
             cvUpdates.put("DAY", "   ");
             db.update("WORD", cvUpdates, null, null);


      }
```

Why do I keep getting

```
sqlite> select * from word;
||
```

beating my head against the wall on this one...

Comment: are you getting any error in logcat while inserting or updating?

Comment: Try including `db.open()` and `db.close()` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the SQL-string you're building to create your tables:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(WORD TEXT, DEFINITION TEXT, DAY TEXT)"
```

This will create:

```
CREATE TABLE WORD(WORD TEXT, DEFINITION TEXT, DAY TEXT)
```

You can see that it's missing a white-space between the table-name and the fields (`... WORD( ...`).

If you have a look at your LogCat output, you might notice that the `execSQL()`-method throws an `SQLException` telling you that the SQL-String is invalid. You should always catch those Exceptions!

Just for the sake of completeness: The `SQLException`-class extends `RuntimeException`, which is an unchecked exception. More on this can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Answer (score 0):

It was actually because, almost directly after the DB was created, I was using a null HashMap to insert some values into it instead of populating the HashMap with the return of my method (which actually worked.. I just forgot to use it) Doh! Thanks guys.